# Is there a way to access extras in onResume?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm starting an activity with `startActivity()` but there will be times when that activity is already active. In this case I'd like to be able to access `extras` in the `onResume()` method.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested

 just override onResume in activity class like this

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.getExtras().getString("foo");
}
```

Comment: I am putting extras like this in the intent before starting it. Is this the right way? `intent.putExtra("foo", "one");`

Comment: screw it. I went with sharedPreferences. which seems to work much better